# Showing/hiding a box containing a Facebook profile

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, query-selector

I see that there are quite some words that are appearing double or more times in my code.

I'm thinking there might be a more efficient way of writing this code, only I don't have the knowledge to do so.

```
function transitionData(data) {
    if($("div#facebook div#notice").is(":visible")) {
        $("div#facebook div#heading *").fadeOut();
        $("div#facebook div#notice").animate({"opacity":"0"}, function() {
            $("div#facebook div.wrapper > img:first-child").attr("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/"+data.id+"/picture?type=normal");
            $("div#facebook h3").html("Facebook account of <b>"+data.name+"</b>");
            $("div#facebook div#heading a").attr("href", "http://www.facebook.com/"+data.username);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child td:first-child b").text(data.id);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr td:first-child b").text(data.first_name);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child b").text(data.last_name);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child td:first-child+td b").text(data.gender.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.gender.slice(1));
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.locale);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.username);

            $("div#facebook div#notice").slideUp();
            $("div#facebook div.wrapper").slideDown();
            $("div#facebook div#heading *").fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        $("div#facebook div#heading *, div#facebook div.wrapper").fadeOut(function() {
            $("div#facebook div.wrapper > img:first-child").attr("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/"+data.id+"/picture?type=normal");
            $("div#facebook h3").html("Facebook account of <b>"+data.name+"</b>");
            $("div#facebook div#heading a").attr("href", "http://www.facebook.com/"+data.username);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child td:first-child b").text(data.id);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr td:first-child b").text(data.first_name);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child b").text(data.last_name);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child td:first-child+td b").text(data.gender.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.gender.slice(1));
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.locale);
            $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.username);

            $("div#facebook div#heading *, div#facebook div.wrapper").fadeIn();            
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can store and use for example $("div#facebook") in a variable

Comment: and duplicate code parts in the if/else loop can be made as a function with the parameter `data`

Comment: I've looked at this for 15 seconds and realized I would use a template engine for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a lead from [konijn](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43938/38383), and take it a few steps further.

- First, as konijn did, we break out the repeated parts into their own method.
- As Daniel Ruf noted, we can save a lot of characters by caching `div#facebook` node as a variable, and then using [`.find(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to look for subnodes.
- Also, we don't need to specify the HTML element type when looking for nodes, so we can go from `div#facebook` to just `#facebook`.
- The callback called on completion of methods such as `fadeOut()` is called for every element that is faded out (for example), where you probably only want this to happen once. Thus, we can replace the call back with a promise that will be called only once, after all of the animation is complete.
- I'd also give the same warning as konijn regarding the approach of using elements in a certain order:

  > Finally, I must say, your approach is terrible. Your elements should have unique id's ( first_name, username etc. etc. ), the way you select elements now is a maintenance nightmare. Re-ordering the elements means re-writing the JavaScript code!

This gives us a version of the code that looks like this:

```
function transitionData(data) {
    var $facebook = $("#facebook");
    var $notice = $facebook.find("#notice"); 
    if($notice.is(":visible")) {
        var $headingStar = $facebook.find("#heading *");
        $headingStar.fadeOut();
        $notice.animate({"opacity":"0"}, function() {
            transitionDataDone(data, $facebook)
            $notice.slideUp();
            $facebook.find(".wrapper").slideDown();
            $headingStar.fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        var $elementsToFade = $facebook.find("#heading *, .wrapper");
        $elementsToFade.fadeOut();
        $elementsToFade.promise().done(function() {
            transitionDataDone(data, $facebook);
            $elementsToFade.fadeIn();
        });
    }
}

function transitionDataDone(data, $facebook){
    $facebook.find(".wrapper > img:first-child").attr("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/"+data.id+"/picture?type=normal");
    $facebook.find("h3").html("Facebook account of <b>"+data.name+"</b>");
    $facebook.find("#heading a").attr("href", "http://www.facebook.com/"+data.username);
    $facebook.find("tr:first-child td:first-child b").text(data.id);
    $facebook.find("tr:first-child+tr td:first-child b").text(data.first_name);
    $facebook.find("tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child b").text(data.last_name);
    $facebook.find("tr:first-child td:first-child+td b").text(data.gender.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.gender.slice(1));
    $facebook.find("tr:first-child+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.locale);
    $facebook.find("tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.username);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a once over,

- You have far more than a `few words` that are copy pasted, you could extract all the common statements into a common function:

  ```
  function transitionDataDone( data ){
      $("div#facebook div.wrapper > img:first-child").attr("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/"+data.id+"/picture?type=normal");
      $("div#facebook h3").html("Facebook account of <b>"+data.name+"</b>");
      $("div#facebook div#heading a").attr("href", "http://www.facebook.com/"+data.username);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child td:first-child b").text(data.id);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr td:first-child b").text(data.first_name);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child b").text(data.last_name);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child td:first-child+td b").text(data.gender.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.gender.slice(1));
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.locale);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.username);
  }
  ```
- Once you have done that, you will notice that you are not repeating too many jQuery selectors. The only one that stands out to me is `$("div#facebook div#notice");` If you cache this selector and apply the previous code, you get something like this (not tested, but you should get the gist):

  ```
  function transitionData(data) {
      var $divNotice = $("div#facebook div#notice"); 
      if($divNotice.is(":visible")) {
          $("div#facebook div#heading *").fadeOut();
          $divNotice.animate({"opacity":"0"}, function() {
              transitionDataDone( data )
              $divNotice.slideUp();
              $("div#facebook div.wrapper").slideDown();
              $("div#facebook div#heading *").fadeIn();
          });
      } else {
          $("div#facebook div#heading *, div#facebook div.wrapper").fadeOut(function() {
              transitionDataDone( data );
              $("div#facebook div#heading *, div#facebook div.wrapper").fadeIn();            
          });
      }
  }

  function transitionDataDone( data ){
      $("div#facebook div.wrapper > img:first-child").attr("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/"+data.id+"/picture?type=normal");
      $("div#facebook h3").html("Facebook account of <b>"+data.name+"</b>");
      $("div#facebook div#heading a").attr("href", "http://www.facebook.com/"+data.username);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child td:first-child b").text(data.id);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr td:first-child b").text(data.first_name);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child b").text(data.last_name);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child td:first-child+td b").text(data.gender.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.gender.slice(1));
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.locale);
      $("div#facebook tr:first-child+tr+tr td:first-child+td b").text(data.username);
  }
  ```
- Finally, I must say, your approach is terrible. Your elements should have unique id's ( `first_name`, `username` etc. etc. ), the way you select elements now is a maintenance nightmare. Re-ordering the elements means re-writing the JavaScript code!

Comment: totally right, unique CSS IDs are much faster and better to select